# Is there any function or package to generate md5crypt string in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, crypt

We'd like to encrypt user password in exported file from Oracle, password should be md5crypt string, like $1$salt$hash.

```
--PowerShell Git function example:
Get-Md5Crypt('sachiko')
$1$gfJ1cxju47$hLcMO7LZyA2Z74yTP.TmW1
```

I'm just wondering "DBMS_CRYPTO" function can generate MD5 with salt. So far, can't find any good examples though. If there is no appropriate function or package provided by Oracle, we can apply any alternative way.

Comment: Take a look at `dbms_crypto.mac`. Note that Oracle uses `raw` data type for the key and also returns `raw` data type for the hash (your example seems to have strings for everything). Also, Oracle has a very developed security framework, and md5crypt was one of the algorithms one could use - that is **deprecated** as of Oracle 21, as being insufficiently secure. You may want to consider that too. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/upgrd/behavior-changes-deprecated-desupport-oracle-database.html#GUID-C741BB7C-0A09-4DF0-9EDB-9A60259F1F8D

Comment: @Sachiko did my suggestion help? Can you acknowledge with some feedback

Comment: @Sachiko: would you accept the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an oracle function that will return an encrypted sha512 output. As mentioned above, if you plan on saving the value it should be in a column defined as RAW ie hash_val RAW(700). as DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH returns a RAW datatype.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION HASH_SHA512 (
    psINPUT IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    rHash RAW (512);
    BEGIN
    rHash := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (TO_CLOB (psINPUT), 
dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
    RETURN (LOWER (RAWTOHEX (rHash)));
    END HASH_SHA512;
/


SELECT HASH_SHA512('testsha512 output') from dual

7a1b50a71560fb87ce90013b9845a36edf26964655930365aec44ea1f1a9f45763f082b148b8b99dc11b71ea5336e3a93f6382ced2a914434352c2ddb48ad69e
```

Comment: So sorry for my late reply due to my sick. Many thanks for your wonderful sample!! I never imagine how to use DBMS_CRYPTO as function. I'll also try to apply MD5 $1$salt$hash style, too. Thank you so much:)

Comment: @Sachiko your welcome As mentioned above MD5 will be deprecated and than you would have to change your code if you need Oracle support or port to a new release